# UIScrollView scrollRectToVisible isn't doing anything

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm not really sure why this isn't working, hopefully you can help me find the missing piece. I have a `UIScrollView` with paging enabled. I'm using it for side-scrolling through a tutorial. I have a button that when tapped should scroll the user back to the beginning of the tutorial. I originally tried using the scroll view's frame as the rect to scroll to because that `CGRect` should represent the first page. I've tried a couple of different `CGRects` to no avail though.

```
- (IBAction) touchedButtonReturnToBeginning:(id)sender {
    // I've tried several CGRect's, none of which cause the UIScrollView to move.
    // CGRect beginning = self.containerScrollView.frame
    // CGRect beginning = self.containerScrollView.bounds;
    CGRect beginning = CGRectMake(0, 44, 1, 1);
    [self.containerScrollView scrollRectToVisible:beginning animated:YES];
}
```

I have verified that `self.containerScrollView` is hooked up in my `xib` as well as the `touchedButtonReturnToBeginning` action is connected to my button. I've used my debugger to step through this method, so I have verified that it is getting called. All of the variables are appropriately set, but when I call `scrollRectToVisible` the scroll view just doesn't do anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: To clarify, when you touch the button to scroll, the `touchedButtonReturnToBeginning` **is** called, correct?

Comment: Yes, I've put an NSLog in the method and I've used the debugger to step through and I see that it is happening.

Comment: Have you checked the `contentSize` property of your `UIScrollView`? 
When this issue hits me it's usually caused by an invalid (e.g. `{0,0}`) content size on the scroll view..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know why that wouldn't work, but have you tried `[self.containerScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES]`?

Comment: That DID work. Why in the heck doesn't scrollRect work though? That is SO strange..

Answer (score 5):

To make scrollRectToVisible works check your self.containerScrollView.contentSize. It should be big enough :)

Comment: It was `0 x 0`, now I set it equal to its frame but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Content size should be bigger then scroll frame. In other way not only scrollRectToVisible will not work, but also scroll itself will not do anything.

Comment: Shouldn't it be set automatically? And if not, what is the formula by which I have to set it? What's the corelation between the content size and it's bounds or frame?

Comment: Here is good explanation how scrollView works  http://oleb.net/blog/2014/04/understanding-uiscrollview/